# Как в WinApi реализована обработка флагов?

Tags: winapi, c++

Например параметр `dwStyle` в `createWindow` получает скажем не один флаг, а два или больше, допустим это `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VSCROLL`, но а как дальше это будет обрабатываться? То есть там в реализации функции есть список всех возможных сочетаний после побитовых операций?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Каждый флаг - отдельный бит в числе. Задаются они через битовое  ИЛИ (|). Соответственно проверяются они битовым И (&). Используя битовые операции можно установить и проверить каждый бит(флаг) отдельно от других. Почитать можно [тут](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/bitovye-operatory) Или в любом другом месте по запросу "битовые операции C++"

Comment: Не обязательно каждый флаг = отдельный бит. Возможно, что флаг соответствует какой-то комбинации битов. Например, WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000L, т.е. уже включает в себя WS_BORDER = 0x00800000L

Comment: Чаще всего это говорит о том, что данное значение является комбинацией нескольких флагов.

Comment: @Dmitry Lepeshkin, соглашусь.